# Invalid numbers and output on listing when using linerange on lstinputlisting

Tags: numbering, listings, pdf, tcolorbox, output

I'm trying to use `linerange` inside a `lstinputlisting`. The command is able to read the file but omitts the content of the first line. I would expect if I use the following code to see the last line of `List 1` at the beggining of `List 2`, this corresponds to line 20 on the source file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}


\begin{document}
% List 1
\lstinputlisting[linerange=10-20, numbers=left]{ERC.sol}
% List 2
\lstinputlisting[linerange=20-30, numbers=left]{ERC.sol}
\end{document}
```

Thats the compiled pdf I'm getting, as you can see line 20 (line 1 on `List 2`) is not displayed correcly and omitted on the second listing:

[image: Invalid number line and shifted content]

Here it is the `ERC.sol` file I'm using.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

/**
 * @dev Interface of the ERC20 standard.
 */
interface ERC20I is IERC20 {
    /**
     * @dev Returns the name of the token.
     */
    function name() external view returns (string memory);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the symbol of the token, usually a shorter version of the
     * name.
     */
    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);

    /** @dev Creates `amount` tokens and assigns them to `account`, increasing
     * the total supply.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event with `from` set to the zero address.
     *
     * Requirements
     *
     * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external;

    /**
     * @dev Destroys `amount` tokens from `account`, reducing the
     * total supply.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event with `to` set to the zero address.
     *
     * Requirements
     *
     * - `account` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `account` must have at least `amount` tokens.
     */
    function burn(address from, uint256 amount) external;
}
```

Comment: line 20 is empty so it is dropped at the end of the first listing, you can show it with `showlines=true`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments ...